# security warning for javascript and css file?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + javascript (jQuery).

I met with the following security warning in browser (at the top of the page in IE) when browse a page -- "An add-on for this web site failed to run. Check the security settings in Internet Options for potential conflicts." The function I developed works fine besides the security warnings. I am using IE 8. Any ideas why there is security warnings and how to resolve?

Here is the code I added to BlueBand.master to refer the js/css files in head section. I am developing a webpart which such script files will impact (i.e. my webpart will generate a div called "tabs" which such below scripts will impact). Any security issues?

```
 <link type="text/css" href="_layouts/test/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/test/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/test/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/test/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" href="_layouts/test/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $("#tabs").tabs();
     });
 </script>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely has nothing to do with your code.

SharePoint 2007 includes active-X controls.  Depending on your browsers security settings and the sites internet zone, you may not be able to load those components and hence the security warning.

Here is a MS KB article that explains
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931509

Comment: 1. "This most likely has nothing to do with your code" -- why? Before adding such javascript code, there is no such issues. 2. For javascript/css deployment in SharePoint, no need special settings for security -- just copy to layout folder and reference in master page?

Comment: Why? Here is the evidence that leads me to that conclusion. All you have done is add some javascript. If that javascript fails during execution IE displays a small warning triangle in the status bar at the bottom of the browser window. Warnings at the top of the browser window occur when IE blocks things like flash, java applets or other active x controls. Sharepoint ships with ActiveX controls.  I am betting that those activex controls are to blame.  Let us know what you find.